# Shared Drives on Docker

Tags: docker, windows-10

I'm attempting to run docker on my machine. In order to do so I need to grant docker access to local drives. I click on any combination of drives (C, D, and E), click apply, enter my credentials, and after a moment of processing it cheerily goes back to the original state of affairs, that is, the drives not being shared.

[image: Before and after checking C drive (or any other drive)]

I've triple checked that I'm entering the correct password (my account is admin), reset to factory defaults, reset my credentials, uninstalled docker and reinstalled, run docker as admin, and run the suggested powershell script (with the powershell prompt running as admin). When I run the powershell script, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: An error occured (sic) while sharing drive.
See '<path>\docker.exe run --help'.
```

My docker version is 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

EDIT 1:

The mystery continues. I noticed that my C drive wasn't shared, whereas my old laptop, which did have docker up and running successfully, did. So, I went to C, properties, advanced sharing, turned sharing on, ran `net share c` to confirm there is indeed sharing, and then turned docker on. Still didn't have the C drive shared, so I clicked it, hit apply, and not only did it not apply, but following up, `net share c` revealed `This shared resource does not exist.`

EDIT 2:

Intel Virtualization wasn't on, so I went to the BIOS and enabled it. Still not working.

Comment: Finally fixed it. My computer wasn't joined to my work domain, upon joining that fixed things with some security feature of docker which then allowed it to mount.